# WPF: Added line is not shown on the image

Tags: c#, wpf, line

I try to add a line on top of an image. So far it works when I add a line in a new project where I use only a grid and an image.

On the other hand the added line is *not* shown when I use the same code in another project where I also use a grid and an image with other elements. I suppose the line is added but hidden from the image itself or behind another control, grid or border. So my question is, how can I put my line as the **topmost** in front of the image?

```
grid2.Children.Add(myLine);
```

The outline looks like this:
**Window** -> **Grid1**-> **Border**-> **Grid2**-> ***Image*** (On this image I want to add a line)

The line element:

```
    // Add a Line Element
    static Line myLine = new Line
    {
        Stroke = Brushes.GreenYellow,
        StrokeThickness = 2,
        Visibility = Visibility.Visible
    };
```

Here I read both points for the line:

```
private void image_zoom0_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)                                   
        {
            if (_firstPoint)
            {
                grid2.Children.Remove(myLine);                                      // remove line first
                System.Windows.Point position = Mouse.GetPosition(image_zoom0);
                myLine.X1 = position.X;
                myLine.Y1 = position.Y;
                _firstPoint = false;
            }
            else
            {
                System.Windows.Point position = Mouse.GetPosition(image_zoom0);
                myLine.X2 = position.X;
                myLine.Y2 = position.Y;
                _firstPoint = true;

                grid2.Children.Add(myLine);                                         // draw line
                Canvas.SetZIndex(myLine,99);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I read both points of the line with a mouse click (see above).

Comment: You're calling `grid2.Children.Add`, but `grid1.Children.Remove`. Is that a typo in your question?

Comment: In case I read in new points I would like to remove the previous line which has been added to the image.

Comment: Yeah, but you're using **grid1** for the one and **grid2** for the other. That's why it's strongly recommended to use proper names for your UI elements, just to avoid such errors.

Comment: And instead of constantly adding and removing the Line to/from the Grid. you might just toggle its Visibility.

Comment: Ok you are right this is a typo. I changed it on my code. Unfortunately it still does not show the line on top of the image :( Do I need to set another ZIndex for the line or the image?

Comment: You don't need to set a ZIndex at all, as long as the Line is added to grid2 after the Image, which seems to be the case here. Did you set a breakpoint in your MouseLeftButtonDown handler to make sure that it is actually called?

Comment: yes I set a breakpoint and both points for the line are valid, before I set "grid2.Children.Add(myLine);"

Comment: could you post a working sample for the same?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what kind of behavior you are expecting from this code. However, I created a sample wpf app and copied image_zoom0_MouseLeftButtonDown method as is.

Note-

- I have added  Stretch="UniformToFill" for the Image, so that it
  occupy whole screen.
- I have initialized _firstPoint to "false".

## XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" WindowState="Maximized">
<Grid x:Name="grid1">
    <Border>
        <Grid x:Name="grid2">
            <Image x:Name="image_zoom0" Source="Background3.jpg" MouseLeftButtonDown="image_zoom0_MouseLeftButtonDown"  Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

### Code-behind

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    static Line myLine = new Line
    {
        Stroke = Brushes.GreenYellow,
        StrokeThickness = 2,
        Visibility = Visibility.Visible
    };

    bool _firstPoint;

    private void image_zoom0_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            if (_firstPoint)
            {
                grid2.Children.Remove(myLine);                                      // remove line first
                System.Windows.Point position = Mouse.GetPosition(image_zoom0);
                myLine.X1 = position.X;
                myLine.Y1 = position.Y;
                _firstPoint = false;
            }
            else
            {
                System.Windows.Point position = Mouse.GetPosition(image_zoom0);
                myLine.X2 = position.X;
                myLine.Y2 = position.Y;
                _firstPoint = true;

                grid2.Children.Add(myLine);                                         // draw line
                //Canvas.SetZIndex(myLine, 99);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now according to the logic written inside the MouseLeftButtonDown, when you first click on the image a Line is drawn from TopLeft of the Window to the current mouseposition.
Second click will simply remove the line. Third click will again draw the line from your previous mouse position to current mouse position and fourth click will again remove it and so on.